# is eigen dense-sparse matrix product threaded?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I know that sparse-dense product is threaded according to the documentation:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

What about dense-sparse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise, sparse-dense product is multithreaded only if the left-hand-side sparse matrix is row-major. Conversely, dense-sparse products is multithreaded if the right-hand-side sparse matrix is column-major.

Comment: Just a clarification: What is the ordering of the Dense matrix in the above response?